# How to attach a security camera to an existing box?

Tags: exterior, mounting, security, low-voltage

Our house was wired for security cameras, when we moved in, and I'm now getting around to install the cameras on some of the corners.

However, the cameras and the separate mounts on sale today all seem to expect a three-hole mount of 2" in diameter.

What I have on the corners of my house -- with the camera-cables inside -- are 4" boxes with 4 screw-holes (although each box itself is attached to the wall with only two screws).

[image: box with security camera wire inside]
How should I proceed with the installations?

1. Unscrew and replace the existing boxes with something specifically designed for today's cameras? What are they called -- how do I find them?
2. Find some sort of mounting adapter
   for sale? I spent an hour on Amazon already and couldn't find anything -- any hints?
3. Make an adapter by drilling the necessary openings in
   the cover-plates of the existing boxes? Seems easiest, but I worry about security of the result -- though the cover is metal, it may bend and warp with time under the weight of the camera and wind-pressure.

Comment: Being low-voltage devices they don't really call for a box. How badly damaged is the siding behind the current boxes? I'd consider removing them and mounting directly to the wall.

Comment: Probably not _badly_ damaged, but there is certainly a hole for the wires. Plus two holes made by the existing screws holding the boxes to wall by the ears. If I remove the existing boxes at all, I'd rather replace them with something that would cover the same area...

Comment: Do the boxes have side port exits?  Perhaps they are intended as junction boxes moreso than camera mounts, and I bet they're standard boxes too.  I've been known to go with the "modify covers" option but first figure out where to get more covers in case you booger one up.

Comment: Yes, there are side port exits -- all closed. I suspect, the low-voltage installer just left the wires hanging and the general contractor then made an electrician-apprentice hide them in boxes so as to pass the inspection :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many camera's like this popular Lorex model:

[image]

come with a small 2" surface mounting "Plate" that you can use if you don't have electrical box mounting.  They also screw into a 1/2" weatherproof threaded knockout, so that they can be used with 4" weatherproof flood light accessory plates:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Tyson, these two covers you posted look perfect! What are the names? Can't find anything like that on Amazon :(

Comment: Type “weatherproof round cover” in your favorite big box stores search.  This is a very common electrical dept item, not hard to locate.

Comment: Thanks, I used "Google Image Search" in the mean time. There is even an option with a [built-in swivel](https://www.amazon.com/Swivel-Fixture-Hanger-Dedicated-Ground/dp/B00V7TPBES/)!

Comment: Don’t forget to vote when an answer helps you along the way ;]